# How to iterate over all elements of Tensor and get index

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have a  Keras Sequential model with customized Dense layers, and I want to iterate over the kernel and bias Tensor of each layer, being able to access the element value and the index of where it is. I have the following code:

```
l = []
for i in range(len(nn.layers)):
    t1, t2 = nn.layers[i].kernel, nn.layers[i].bias
    for j in range(t1.shape[0]):
        for k in range(t1[j].shape[0]):
            l.append((t1[j][k].numpy(), i, j, k))
    for j in range(t2.shape[0]):
        l.append((t2[j], i))
```

Where the variable `nn` is the Sequential model with a certain number of layers, each one with a number of nodes. It works for my  purposes, but it's not very efficient. Is there any (preferably a more TensorFlow-like way) of achieving the same result? I'm using TensorFlow 2.0 by the way.

Comment: You can already access the weights where they are, why do you need to store them in another data structure?

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat as seen on my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58421182/how-to-lock-specific-values-of-a-tensor-in-tensorflow) I'm trying to implement the lottery ticket hypothesis, and to get the weights I'm going to prune in my network, I need them sorted somehow. I'm  adapting the example code that simon gave me, and it's working, but the pruning process is kinda slow, I'm trying to see where I can optimize it.